# Do incentives suffer the same way as voting systems?

Tags: game-theory

Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem establishes the weakness of voting systems. In posts on social issues, one often sees lament about the ‘misalignment’ of incentives. A natural question to ask, then, is whether there exists a theorem similar to Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem for incentives. Indeed, it might even turn out that that incentives can be shown to be the flip-side (i.e., the dual) of voting systems, and with Arrow’s Impossibility Theorem consequently directly applying to them.

Comment: I think this needs to be made more precise.  Arrow's results concern the difficulties encountered when you try to map individual preferences onto groups.  What, precisely, is the analogy you are hoping for here?

Comment: the difficulties encountered when you try to map individual incentives onto outcomes.

Comment: What's an outcome?  Who decides how to evaluate different outcomes?  In the usual Arrow variants questions of utility are avoided since we just ask voting to pass some obvious tests.  There is no "relative" component to worry about.

Comment: You might be interesting in the so-called [Braess paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braess%27s_paradox).  There, against all intuition, one sees a simple system with fairly trivial utility issues in which giving people more options lowers their equilibrium expectations.  It's not really Arrow-like, but it certainly shows that widening the space of choices doesn't always make things better.

Comment: I don't think there is such an analogy. Mechanism design looks at issues of implementability, i.e., can we find a mechanism (that gives incentives) to implement a certain social choice function? The answer always depends on the social choice function and the constraints. Often there is a mechanism that implements the desired social choice function. One main difference between voting and the more general mechanism design is that transfers are often allowed, so there are more tools to achieve certain outcomes than in voting.

Comment: The Braess paradox reminds me of the adage "Constraint produces better art."

Comment: Something like the Braess paradox occurs within mathematics itself. One such instance is Runge's phenomenon, that going to higher degrees does not always improve accuracy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon